# Run a php file daily at specific time

Tags: wp-cron

I'm trying to add a cron job to run file daily at 7pm.

How can i add the file run command and specify to run it at 7pm ?

```
// Scheduled Action Hook
function run_my_script( ) {
// run my file : mysite.com/cron.php
}
// Schedule Cron Job Event
function USERS_MONITORING() {
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'USERS_MONITORING' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'USERS_MONITORING' );
}
}
add_action( 'wp', 'USERS_MONITORING' );
```

I don't know if there is a better solution.

Comment: What file are you trying to run? If it's just a generic PHP file, I'd suggest using the native cron of your server.

Comment: A php file on my server ( question updated ). The native cron of my server does'nt work.

Comment: WP Cron doesn't run files, it fires actions/hooks, the code in your question should generate a fatal error as you've defined a function with the same name twice, and function names should be unique. I would also be careful having standalone files like `cron.php`, for security reasons. I could hit that file repeatedly to cause a denial of service attack via resource exhaustion

Comment: Ok noted. Any suggestions to do the job ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the PHP file and do the tasks, if WP-cron is your only option.

```
// Scheduled Action Hook
function run_my_script( ) {
    require_once('related/path/to/php/file.php');
}
// Schedule Cron Job Event
function USERS_MONITORING() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'USERS_MONITORING' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( strtotime('07:00:00'), 'daily', 'USERS_MONITORING' );
    }
}
add_action( 'USERS_MONITORING', 'run_my_script' );
```

Note that you need to include the related path. If you want to access the PHP file by its URL, you need to use cURL instead.

Also, as @rarst mentioned in one of his posts:

> **Note :** WP Cron isn't guaranteed to run at precise time since it is
>   trigerred by visits to the site. I am not confident if recurrent runs
>   will "stick" at midnight or will slowly slip from there, you might
>   need to readjust periodically.

Comment: Just FYI, you can add wp-cron.php to your system crontab to make 100% sure it runs at a specific interval. (basically wget /path/wp-cron.php)