# Import JSON feed into Wordpress Post (wp_insert_post) every 24 hours

Tags: json, wp-insert-post

I am importing a JSON feed using a php file I am then looping through the JSON data and creating/updating a post using the wp_insert_post function. I want to query the JSON feed every 24 hours to sync any new information to Wordpress. I thought having something like zapier hit the page every 24 hours to run the php could work but it seemed there must be a better way to do that in wordpress/php?

Comment: Have you looked at [wp_schedule_event](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/)?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/276300/run-a-php-file-daily-at-specific-time contains nearly everything you need. Although setting cron on the server would be preferable all ways round in my opinion. Especially since if no one visits the site, this would not run. With "proper" cron, it will run - like clockwork.